# Репликация кэша

Tags: java, ehcache

Кэш на EhCache 2.10.2. Репликация не асинхронная (replicateAsynchronously=false) на двух серверах.

Получается следующая ситуация:

1. Приходит HTTP запрос на первый сервер S1
2. S1 не находит объект в кэше и загружает его из БД с состоянием "А" и кладёт в кэш
3. В S1 меняется состояние объекта на "Б", объект сохраняется в БД и кладётся в кэш
4. S1 отвечает успехом на запрос
5. Извне приходит следующий запрос и попадает во второй сервер S2
6. S2 находит в кэше объект с состоянием "А"
7. S2 отвечает ошибкой на запрос, т.к. у объекта должно было быть состояние "Б"
8. Объект в кэше обновляется на объект с состоянием "Б"

Проблема возникает из-за того, что когда мы делаем put в кэш, мы получаем управление обратно когда десериализованный объект отправлен на другой сервер, но не тогда когда он там десериализуется и фактически обновится. Т.е. состояние "Б" может успеть обновиться до 6 пункта, а может и нет.

Можно как-то настроить EhCache, чтобы он блокировал put до конца?

Может быть EhCache на что-то другое заменить или полностью подход переделать?

*Примечание. Запросы последовательные, второй запрос (п.5) приходит только после получения ответа на первый (п.4). Например, первый запрос - аутентификация пользователя и если она успешна, то делается второй запрос - получение информации о пользователе. Если, допустим, время между п.3 и п.8 составляет 100мс, то ситуацию бы исправила задержка ответа (п.4) на эти 100 мс, т.к. к моменту второго запросы был бы уже нужный статус "Б".*

Comment: Боюсь, это просто физически невозможно. Если вы кэшируете данные, вы должны либо быть готовыми к неконсистентному состоянию, либо не кэшировать данные. Де-факто у вас получаются две системы (бд и кэш), которые не могут атомарно обновиться вдвоем, поэтому вы не можете решить эту проблему. Вы можете сделать так, что пункт 4 будет выполняться только после обновления кэша на всех серверах, но это на самом деле только подкинет вам проблем, а с оригинальной ничего не сделает.

Comment: @Etki какие могут быть проблемы если просто ответ на первый запрос будет чуть дольше?

Comment: Тому клиенту, который запрашивает, это не подкинет. Всем остальным - подкинет, потому что баг превратится в гейзенбаг. Вы же понимаете, что если вы включите синхронную репликацию, вы просто отодвинете время ответа клиента, а с самой проблемой ничего не сделаете?

Comment: @Etki Видимо я плохо объяснил. 5 пункт выполняется строго после 4-го. Это два последовательных запроса.

Comment: Вы можете гарантировать последовательность запросов только в том случае, если у вас один клиент.

Comment: @Etki Оба запроса от одного клиента, который их шлёт по очереди.